# How to add Cucumber feature files support in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cucumber-jvm, feature-file

I've added the `Gherkin` and `Cucumber for Java` plugins into Android Studio and restarted it, but when I create a new file from the Project window, the `Cucumber feature files` type is not listed.

What are the steps to have the `Cucumber feature files` support in Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I did not installed the plugins the way it is supposed to be, via the Plugins page of the settings. Oops

Comment: Can you plz explain How you installed these plugins via AS ? I don't see them listed neither on "browse plugins" nor on "install jetbrains plugin..." pages.

Comment: You can download them on https://plugins.jetbrains.com/ and then in the Plugins page of AS, you must click on "Install plugin from disk..."

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. can they get auto- updated this way ?

Comment: I don't know, at the end I did not used them because I was not able to get my Cucumber tests to work...